# Remove parentheses from array value converted to string

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I have a textview and when displaying text there are parentheses in the text. I want to eliminate them. This is my code:

```
self.txtpstn.text =  "\(self.no_pstn.self as NSArray)"
self.txtmobile.text =  "\(self.no_mobile.self as NSArray)"
```

This is the display on the application:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join:

```
self.txtpstn.text =  "\((self.no_pstn.self as NSArray).componentsJoined(by: ","))"
self.txtmobile.text =  "\(self.no_mobile.self as NSArray).componentsJoined(by: ","))"
```

Comment: this is very helpful, but what if i want to add a new line or enter

Comment: ohh i know, .componentsJoined(by: "\n"))" .. okok thanks

Comment: Why cast to NSArray?

Comment: No special reason.

Comment: Then don’t. Don’t add needless casts.

Comment: Its from the question.

Comment: Don’t copy and paste bad code from the question into your answer. It’s better if the answer improves the code.